# Pasar datos de un datagrid a otro en diferentes formularios

Tags: c#, visual-studio, datagrid

Tengo un formulario frm1 donde tengo un datagrid y en una de las celdas tengo el evento celldoubleclick, esto me abre un segundo formulario frm2 el cual tiene una datagrid y al hacer doble click sobre una celda quiero que ese valor me aparezca en la cel del frm1.

Asi obtengo el valor de la celda del frm2:

```
  Public static string ValueAccount;
  string cellvalue = Convert.ToString(dataGridAccounts.CurrentCell.Value);
  ValueAccount = cellvalue;
```

Ahora como hago para que esa valor de la variable ValueAccount me aparezca en la celda del frm1 donde hice doble click?

lo estoy asiendo de esta manera, pero solo pasa una vez el dato, si vuelvo a llamar el frm2 ya no cambia el dato aunque yo seleccione otro valor del datagrid.
Esto tengo en el evento celldoubleclick en frm1

```
frm2 frmaccount = new frm2();
frmaccount.ShowDialog();
GridRowsCoti.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value = frm2.ValueAccount;
```

Comment: Si es posible, puede compartir el codigo mas completa? Los functions CellDoubleClick frm1 y frm2 con los parametros? Y el class de frm2? Gracias

Answer (score -1):

Para que el valor pueda volver a ser transferido de frm2 a frm1 debes asegurarte de colocar esta parte del código en el evento "CellDoubleClick" del grid que está en el frm2, quedaría algo así:

```
private void GridRowsCoti_CellDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    cellvalue = Convert.ToString(GridRowsCoti.CurrentCell.Value);
    ValueAccount = cellvalue;  
}
```

Comment: eso lo expongo en la pregunta principal amigo.

Comment: Entiendo, ¿Te fijaste si el valor de la variable "ValueAccount" cambia haciendo debbug?